# How restore a main parent branch back to original removing all new merged branches

Tags: git, gitlab

1. Created a main project branch (clean and no merged branches).
2. Several branches from master branch are merged to project branch.
   e.g.: branchA, branchB, branchC
3. I want to restore main project branch back to its original form or state (back to #1) without all merged branches.

How can I do this? I tried reverting or restoring but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Working alone on this repo? *(i'm asking because it will determine which strategy to adopt)*

Comment: @RomainValeri. Yes, the other branches are just test branches. Thank you for asking sir.

Comment: Just reset the HEAD to prior to the merge commits, then - `git reset HEAD~<number of merge commits> --hard`

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Thank you for replying. So it will be? git reset HEAD~3 --hard

Comment: @randyk69 It could be more cautious to first do a `git log --oneline` to spot the exact commit you want to get back to, store its hash (SHA-1 identifier) then do `git reset --hard <HashYouStoredEarlier>`

Comment: Also note that you'll need to use `--force` next time you push to your remote repo to force update the old ref.

Comment: @RomainValeri. Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Out of curiosity and i hope you won't mind me asking, what if I just want to remove only the committed branchB?

Comment: @randyk69 Reset the main branch as we suggested then re-merge branchB in.

Comment: @RomainValeri. Thank you for all your suggestions guys. God bless you all!